# RedLaser camera overlay goes black

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

After about 15 seconds the live preview of the BarCodePickerController will go black yet the device will still scan. What is causing the screen to go black yet allow the device to still scan?

This happens on iPads and iPhones

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by 2 instances of the same BarCodePickerController. I recently came across this issue that a client was having and diagnosed the problem to them adding the BarCodePickerController as a subView twice. The camera would work for about 15 seconds then go black while the reader was still working. Hope this helps anyone else that stumbles across it.